# Terraform SSM module - ignore existing keys if value is passed is null

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm a bit new to this so I apologize if it's basic.
We have an AWS parameters store managed by terraform.
we use a model for it:
the values of the keys are not stored and each time we do terraform apply we need to enter them manually.
suppose id like to add a new key, id need to edit the tf files to add another key and when i got terraform apply i need to re enter all the values of existing keys and then enter the value for the new key.

Im looking for a way to add to terraform another key, when ill terraform apply, i want terraform to see that only new key is added so all the current existing key are not to be modified. i was thinking about passing null to the variable of the existings keys and then terraform see it is null it will disregard the parameters store and wont touch it.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "default" {
  count           = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
  name            = "${module.label.id}-parameter"
  type            = var.type
  value           = var.value
  description     = var.description
  tier            = var.tier
  key_id          = var.key_id
  overwrite       = var.overwrite
  allowed_pattern = var.allowed_pattern
  
}
```

This is the module i’m using.

Comment: That's not how it works. If you set the existing parameters to null the values will be removed. The best way to do this is **not** by providing the values on the CLI, rather having a tfvars file and adding new values there. As a bonus it will be picked up automagically during plan/apply.

Comment: yea i know, but is there a way to do that? the boss dont want values stored locally and not on a repo (although they are actually stored on beckend)

Comment: The behavior you are describing is the default behavior of Terraform. It is unclear why you are trying to do this with extra steps.

Comment: I have tf files with 10 parameter store resources. say i want to add one. then i go and modify the code to add one. when i terraform apply, it will request variables for all the existing parameter store objects as well as the new one.i want to to press enter upon each question and make terraform "understand" that i dont want him replacing the values in the keys with null. just pass over them